# Building Tensorflow From Source Using Bazel, Cannot Find op_def.pb.h

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Platform : Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tensorflow: 1.4.0, Installed From Source

Python Version: 2.7

Bazel Version: 0.6.1

GPU model and memory: laptop CPU

Exact command to reproduce: `bazel build -c opt  //tensorflow/core/user_ops:rest_api.so --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"`

My BUILD file in `/tensorflow/core/user_ops`:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

cc_library(
    name = "rest_api_dependencies",
    srcs = glob(["*.c", "*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.h", "*.hpp", "dict.c"]),
    linkopts = ["-pthread", "-lev", "-fexceptions"],
    deps = ["//tensorflow/core:framework", 
            "//tensorflow/core:reader_base"],
)

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "rest_api.so",
    srcs = ["redis_reader.cc"],
    deps = ["rest_api_dependencies"],
)
```

I've been trying to build the shared library for my custom op reader via bazel, but the compiler is unable to find the op_def.pb.h file. It doesn't seem to be in the `tensorflow/core/framework` folder, but it is in `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework` (generated from an earlier unrelated build). So I added an include directive to this directory in my source code (`rest_api.h`), yet it is still unable to locate the `op_def.pb.h` file. I was hoping someone here who has experience building tensorflow from source with bazel could help me out here.

Comment: Have you ever figured where `op_def.pb.h` is?